# Ionic Validation - show error message like material

Tags: angular, validation, user-interface, ionic-framework, angular-material

I've been working on a Login and Registration Page in Ionic 5. I wanted to display error messages below the input text field like here

[image]

So I implemented Angular Responsive Forms

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => console.log(data));

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email
      ]],
      password: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^(([a-zA-Z][^:.*/}{;])*\d*)$')
      ]]
    });
  }

  get email(){
    return this.myForm.get('email');
  }

  get password(){
    return this.myForm.get('password');
  }
```

After doing that, I created a form with two ion-input fields.

```html
<ion-item class="input_item">
  <ion-label position="floating">E-Mail</ion-label>
  <ion-input formControlName="email" position="floating"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<div class="validation-errors">
    <div class="error-message" *ngIf="email.errors && email.dirty || email.touched">
      Your E-Mail is invalid!
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use this class "validation-errors" but it didn't display the message the way I wanted.
I managed to get it to look like this

[image]

But is there some easier way to display the error message the way Angular Material does it? Is there something from Ionic I can use, or do I have to implement Angular Material UI components?

Thanks for answering.

**UPDATE**: Since this question has been gaining some traction since my original post and there doesn't seem to be a simpler solution I wanted to post the used styles for anyone passing by:

```css
.validation-errors {
    font-size: small;
    color: var(--ion-color-danger, #f1453d);
}

/* These are necessary to make the underline red */
ion-item.invalid {
    --highlight-background: var(--ion-color-danger, #f1453d);
}

ion-item {
    --highlight-color-invalid: var(--ion-color-primary);
}
```

with the inclusion of this in the template

```html
<ion-item [class.invalid]="email.errors && email.touched">
```

Answer (score 7):

In Ionic 6, this is made awesomely simple by using the `error` slot on ion-item.

See the docs here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#slots

Example:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
  <ion-input formControlName="firstName"></ion-input>
  <span slot="error">Name is required</span>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Cool. But how to make it visible?..

Comment: Found the answer there: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24445

Comment: Great :) I'll just state it here in full in case the link goes dead. The error slot is only visible if the ion-item element has a class "ion-invalid". In Angular Ionic, this is being done automatically by your form. In other frameworks/vanilla JS, you have to add that class yourself.

Comment: Its DEPRECATED in V7. Better to use https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#helper--error-text

Comment: @MaheshKS The problem with this property is that it does not show the error until the input is blurred, as long as the user continues on the input the error will not appear.

Comment: In V7 the error text feature follows the Material Design spec and was only intended for simple errors (at most 1 error) to show more follow this approach: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/27890#issuecomment-1658371251